# I solved jenkins auth fail problem but i don't know why?

Tags: jenkins

Background: My Jenkins is Deploy by docker at target server A.There is 4 intranet target servers(inner server) ABCD.Try to deploy code by plugin **Public over SSH** to target server C,When I try to establish a connection from jenkins to target server C,There is
**jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Message [Auth fail]]**

My Finnal solution: Put target server's id_rsa.pub to target server's authorized_keys.and i don't know why it works.

here is some of my trys:

1. put jenkins root's id_rsa.pub to target server root's authorized_keys
2. put jenkins jenkins's(user) id_rsa.pub to  target server root's authorized_keys
3. create jenkins user at target server and repeat 1,2.this time put into target server's jenkins user.

when I try this,ssh and scp works correctly.but jenkins **Public over SSH ** can't.and now though I solved this but I want to know the reason.  thanks for tolerate my gramma..

Comment: Voting to close this as it's not a coding question.